# Merge and synonymize [exponent] and similar

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently there is a number of similar tags:

- [exponent](/questions/tagged/exponent) (71)
- [exponential](/questions/tagged/exponential) (59)
- [exponentiation](/questions/tagged/exponentiation) (38)
- [exponents](/questions/tagged/exponents) (11)

I think all should be merged and synonymized into `[exponent]`.

Answer (score 3):

[exponential](/questions/tagged/exponential) and [exponentiation](/questions/tagged/exponentiation) are both about the exponential function and other exponentiation functions ((*a*, *b*) ↦ *a*<sup>*b*</sup>). I think they can safely be merged.

There are a few questions about scientific or exponential notation (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082651/assign-and-calculate-by-exponential-notation) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193815/displaying-6-5235375356299998e-07-without-exponential-notation)) which should be retagged [scientific-notation](/questions/tagged/scientific-notation). It might be worth it to create a synonym [exponential-notation](/questions/tagged/exponential-notation) → [scientific-notation](/questions/tagged/scientific-notation).

I see far more strays in [exponent](/questions/tagged/exponent) and [exponents](/questions/tagged/exponents), so I think they should be reviewed manually, not merged with [exponential](/questions/tagged/exponential). Some should be retagged to [exponential](/questions/tagged/exponential), others to [scentific-notation](/questions/tagged/scentific-notation) (and [floating-point](/questions/tagged/floating-point) if it isn't there already), with odds and ends like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665832/iphone-rsa-algorithm-with-modulus-and-exponent) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621503/rsa-decryption-using-modulus-and-exponent) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352144/how-do-i-combine-n-and-e-to-create-the-public-key-in-rsa). Furthermore, I don't think the tag [exponent](/questions/tagged/exponent) should stay, it's too ambiguous and the better name [exponential](/questions/tagged/exponential) is a completion. Let [exponent](/questions/tagged/exponent) and [exponents](/questions/tagged/exponents) die when all their questions are retagged.